Verifying that the Dedekind cut associated to $\sqrt{2}$ has the property that its square is equal to the Dedekind cut associated with 2
Define $\sqrt{2}$ to be the Dedekind cut $\{q \in \mathbb{Q}\,|\,q^2 <2\text{ or } q < 0\}$. Define $2^*$ to be the Dedekind cut $\{q \in \mathbb{Q}\,|\,q<2\}$. With the standard definition of multiplication of two Dedekind cuts, $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$
\alpha \cdot \beta = \{q \in \mathbb{Q}\,|\,q<a\cdot b\text{ , such that } a \in \alpha, b\in\beta\},
$$
define the set $T$ as follows: $T=\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{2} = \{q \in \mathbb{Q}\,|\,q < p^2 \text{ where }p \in \sqrt{2}\}$.
I would like to verify that the two sets $T$ and $2^*$ are indeed equal. My (incomplete) proof goes as follows:
First, show that $T$ is contained within $2^*$. Let $t$ be an element of $T$.
\begin{align*}
t \in T &\implies t < p^2 \text{ for some }p \in \sqrt{2} \\
        &\implies t < 2 \\
        &\implies t \in 2^* \quad\square.
\end{align*}
Next, show that $2^*$ is contained within $T$. Let $s$ be an element of $2^*$.
\begin{align*}
s \in 2^* &\implies s < 2 \\
          &\implies \text{some fact I cannot see yet!} \\
          &\implies s < t^2 \text{ where } t \in \sqrt{2} \\
          &\implies s \in T \quad \square.
\end{align*}
As far as I can tell, I would need to show that given a rational $s<2$, there must exist and square rational, $t^2$, in between $s$ and $2$ i.e.
$$
\exists \, t^2 \text{ such that } s < t^2 < 2.
$$
If this were true, then step 2 of my proof would hold. Finally my question: Does such a rational $t^2$ exist? Can a concrete example be given or is there an existence style proof?
I would also like to know if this is the "standard" approach for showing that $\sqrt{2}$ has the properties one might expect (is its square equal to 2).

The rationals are dense in the reals so $t$  with $s < t^2 < 2$ exists. Try to find some rational $\epsilon >0$ so that $(s+\epsilon)^2 < 2$.

@CyclotomicField I’m not sure that there exists a $(s+\epsilon)^2$ which could be simultaneously less than 2 and greater than $s$ for all $s< 2$. Take $s=3/2$ for instance

I see I phrased it incorrectly. What I mean is given some element of $2^$ there exists an element of $s \in \sqrt{2}$ with $s^2 \in 2^$. Now find an $\epsilon$ so that $(s+\epsilon)^2 \in 2^*$. This should be general enough to show all $s$ have such an epsilon.

I found this question which provides the details for the inclusion $2^* \subset T$.
